# How to find a Walrasian equilibrium for this economy?

Tags: walrasian

Consider a production economy with 2 goods, 1 and 2, two consumers A and B, and 2 firms $\alpha,\beta$. The consumers' utility functions are
\begin{align}
u_A(x_1^A,x_2^A)=x_1^A+x_2^A-\frac{1}{24}(x_1^A)^2\\
u_B(x_1^B,x_2^B)=x_1^B+2x_2^B-\frac{1}{40}(x_2^B)^2
\end{align}
Consumer A is endowed with 10 units of good 1 and consumer B is endowed with 20 units of good 1. The 2 firms use good 1 as an input to produce good 2 according to the production functions:
\begin{align}
y_2^\alpha=12(\sqrt{1-y_1^\alpha}-1)\\
y_2^\beta=12(\sqrt{4-y_1^\beta}-2)
\end{align}
where $y_1^\alpha<0$ is the amount of good 1 used by firm $\alpha$ to produce $y_2^\alpha>0$ units of good 2. Consumer A wholly owns firm $\alpha$ and consumer B wholly owns firm $\beta$.

I am asked to find a Walrasian equilibrium of this economy. Here's what I have done so far:

For firm $\alpha$, it maximizes its profit:
\begin{align}
\max p_2 y_2^\alpha+p_1y_1^\alpha\\
s.t. y_2^\alpha=12(\sqrt{1-y_1^\alpha}-1)
\end{align}
By lagrange, $y_1^\alpha=1-\frac{36p_2^2}{p_1^2}$ if $p_1\leq 6p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>6p_2$. Then $y_2^\alpha=\frac{72p_2}{p_1}-12$ if $p_1\leq 6p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>6p_2$. Its profit is $\frac{36p_2^2}{p_1}-12p_2+p_1$ if $p_1\leq 6p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>6p_2$.

Similarly, for firm $\beta$, $y_1^\beta=4-\frac{36p_2^2}{p_1^2}$ if $p_1\leq 3p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>3p_2$. Then $y_2^\beta=\frac{72p_2}{p_1}-24$ if $p_1\leq 3p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>3p_2$. Its profit is $\frac{36p_2^2}{p_1}-24p_2+4p_1$ if $p_1\leq 3p_2$ and 0 if $p_1>3p_2$.

For consumer A, he maximizes his utility:
\begin{align}
\max x_1^A+x_2^A-\frac{1}{24}(x_1^A)^2\\
s.t. p_1 x_1^A+p_2 x_2^A=w^A
\end{align}
where $w^A=10p_1+\pi^\alpha$. By lagrange,

$$x^A=[12(1-\frac{p_1}{p_2}）,\frac{w^A}{p_2}+12\frac{p_1}{p_2}(\frac{p_1}{p_2}-1)],\;\;p_1\leq p_2 \;\&\; w^A\geq 12p_1(1-\frac{p_1}{p_2})$$
$$(0,\frac{w^A}{p_2}),\;\;p_1>p_2 \;\& \;w^A\geq 12p_1(1-\frac{p_1}{p_2})$$
$$(\frac{w^A}{p_1},0),\;\;p_1\leq p_2 \;\&\; w^A<12p_1(1-\frac{p_1}{p_2})$$

Similarly, for consumer B,

$$x^A=[\frac{w^B}{p_1}+20\frac{p_2}{p_1}(\frac{p_2}{p_1}-2),20(2-\frac{p_2}{p_1})],\;\;2p_1\geq p_2 \;\& \;w^B\geq 20p_2(2-\frac{p_2}{p_1})$$
$$(0,\frac{w^B}{p_2}),\;\;2p_1<p_2 \;\& \;w^B\geq 20p_2(2-\frac{p_2}{p_1})$$
$$(\frac{w^B}{p_1},0),\;\;2p_1\geq p_2 \;\&\; w^B<20p_2(2-\frac{p_2}{p_1})$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed using the market clearing condition. Any ideas?